# RDGateway NTLM SSO (with azure application proxy)

Tags: kerberos, rds, ntlm, remote-desktop-gateway, rdweb

So, I follow this guide to change my RDS setup to be available through the azure application proxy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/app-proxy/application-proxy-integrate-with-remote-desktop-services

With this setup I would like to create a "true" microsoft365 SSO remote app setup, but it doesn't seem possible at the moment.
Using the documentation I got SSO to the RDweb HTML5 webclient working (using the azure application proxy KDC SSO configuration, and enabling windows auth in IIS). But I'm unable to get SSO working to the gateway.

The connection from the HTML5 RDwebclient to the gateway uses NTLM instead of kerberos (so far for Microsoft trying to phase out NTLM), and so the KDC SSO configuration doesn't work in this case.

Anyone that has an idea how I could get SSO between the webclient and gateway working?

It would be so clean if this worked somehow, so I'm open to any suggestion